# arrange checkbox values in two columns

Tags: php, html

I have a form with check box values i want to arrange the checkbox in two columns instead of

one single long column.

How can i split it to two columns ?

Here is the code :

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="">


<table width="502" border="0">
<tr>
<td>
 Name :
<input type="textbox" name="rcv_group_name" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="add" />
</td>

</tr>

 <tr>
 <td align="left">
 <strong>HEADING</strong>

 <?php 
 $q = "select * from Config_RCV";


  $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0) 
  {
    $k=0;
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r,MYSQLI_NUM)) 
   {


    ?>
    <br> <input type="checkbox" name ="rcv_val[]" value ="<? echo $row[0];?>" />         &nbsp;<? echo $row[1];?> 



   <?

   $k++;
   }
      }


     ?>

  </td>
   </tr>
 <tr>
    <td align="right"><input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit"     style="background-color:#999" />        

   < /td>
    <td height="26" align="left">&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
     </table>
     <form>
```

Answer (score 2):

add another table and make 2 columns by splitting 2'nd result:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0) {
    $k=0;
    echo '<table><tr>';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r,MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    ?>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name ="rcv_val[]" value ="<?php echo $row[0];?>" /> &nbsp;<?php echo $row[1];?> </td>
    <?php
        $k++;
        if($k%2 == 0){
            echo '</tr><tr>';
        }
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use your $k

```
if ($k%2==0){
echo "<br />";
}
```

instead of the lone 
 now

Using tables like above will probably be better for looks

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a second column to your table:

```
echo "<tr>";
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r,MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    if ($i++%2==0) {
        echo "</tr><tr>";
    }
    echo "<td>".$CELL_CONTENT_HERE."</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
```